# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Entities.KRAParameterInfo' and 'string'

Tags: c#, linq

```
lstInitializeGoal = (from itemEmployees in itemsEmployees.Cast<SPListItem>().AsEnumerable()
    select new Business.Entities.InitializeGoal
    {
        UserId = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.LoginName.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.LoginName.ToString()]).Split(';')[0]
            : string.Empty,
        EmployeeName = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.LoginName.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.LoginName.ToString()]).Split('#')[1]
            : string.Empty,
        LeadUserId = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.ReportingTo.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.ReportingTo.ToString()]).Split(';')[0]
            : string.Empty,
        ReportingTo = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.ReportingTo.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.ReportingTo.ToString()]).Split('#')[1]
            : string.Empty,
        Designation = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]).Split('#')[1]
            : string.Empty,
        WorkStatus = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.WorkStatus.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.WorkStatus.ToString()])
            : string.Empty,
        GoalRequired = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.GoalRequired.ToString()]
            ? Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.GoalRequired.ToString()])
            : string.Empty,
        GoalStatus = "Pending",
        KRAParameter = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]
            ? kraParameterColl.FirstOrDefault(tempKRAParameter => 
                tempKRAParameter.Designation == Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]).Split('#')[1])
            : string.Empty,
        IsEnabled = true
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting error on 

KRAParameter = null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()] ? kraParameterColl.FirstOrDefault(tempKRAParameter=>tempKRAParameter.Designation == Convert.ToString(itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]).Split('#')[1]) : string.Empty,

Can anyone plz suggest whats error and why?

Comment: Please have a look back to your post.. is it readable? To avoid such issues SO is showing [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page before asking a question, kindly go through that and edit the question. definitely someone will help you to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the second-to-last assignment in that code, where you appear to have two different types on either side of the `:` in your ternary condition:

```
KRAParameter = (null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()])
    ? kraParameterColl.FirstOrDefault(tempKRAParameter => 
        tempKRAParameter.Designation == Convert.ToString(
            itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]).Split('#')[1])
    : string.Empty
```

Looking specifically at the types, the conditional expression looks something like:

```
KRAParameter = (condition) ? KRAParameterInfo : string;
```

The error is saying that it can't determine the type to assign because there is no common type conversion between a `KRAParameterInfo` and a `string`.

---

A possible fix would be to use the default of the type (which is null for classes):

```
KRAParameter = (null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()])
    ? kraParameterColl.FirstOrDefault(tempKRAParameter => 
        tempKRAParameter.Designation == Convert.ToString(
            itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]).Split('#')[1])
    : default(KRAParameterInfo)
```

Or explicitly convert the first part to a string:

```
KRAParameter = (null != itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()])
    ? Convert.ToString(kraParameterColl.FirstOrDefault(tempKRAParameter => 
        tempKRAParameter.Designation == Convert.ToString(
            itemEmployees[Business.Enums.Employees.Designation.ToString()]).Split('#')[1]))
    : string.Empty
```